# Failed to read artifact descriptor for avalon-framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.1.5-dev

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am programming a java web project with maven. However I have encountered a problem like followings:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor 
>   for avalon-framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.1.5-dev

Then I tried `mvn clean install`, but it does not work, and flowing errors are showed.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project overhaul: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project Quality:overhaul:war:3.4.3-GA: Failed to
>   collect dependencies at com.cloudhopper.proxool:proxool:jar:0.9.1 ->
>   avalon-framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.1.5-dev: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for
>   avalon-framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.1.5-dev: Could not
>   transfer artifact avalon-framework:avalon-framework-api:pom:4.1.5-dev
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Do someone else know how to solve it? I need your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please Execute following steps to get rid of this permanently.

**Step 1 Get root ssl certificate.**

1. open google chrome and navigate to https://repo.maven.apache.org
2. locate lock shaped icon just left side of your url at address bar and click on it!
3. click on details and click on View Certificate
4. now you can see hierarchy of certificate! click on root certificate which would be on top of hierarchy and drag and drop the IMAGE of the certificate which you can see just bellow hierarchy to your desktop.

Thats it! now you have your ssl certificate with you!

**Step 2 install that certificate to java cacerts file.**

1. Download Keystore Explorer tool.
2. Open //YOURJDKPATH/jre/lib/security/cacerts using keystore Explorer tool.
3. add the ssl certificate using import trusted certificate.
4. click on save and close keystore explorer.
5. you may restart system for safer side!

That is it! your problem is solved! If you still face this problem then double check maven is using same jre of which cacerts file you just edited!